# Non-linear equations in GEKKO with constant input range and iterative initial values

Tags: initialization, iteration, gekko, nonlinear-equation

I'm trying to solve non-linear equations in GEKKO using bounds and initial values. The following example illustrates two main problems I'm trying to solve for a larger system of non-linear equations.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

a = m.Const(value=1)
b = m.Const(value=1)
x = m.Var(value=3,lb=0)
y = m.Var(value=3,lb=0)

m.Equation(10**-x + y == a)
m.Equation(x - 10**y == b)

m.solve(disp=False)

print(x.value,y.value)
```

This gives a solution of:

```
[10.999999998] [0.99999999999]
```

Problem 1 - I want to solve *x,y* using an input range of *a* constants, and also not be concerned with rounding errors. For example, can I incorporate an `np.linspace`?

```
a = np.linspace(1,10,10)
```

Problem 2 - By the time *a=4*, the initial value of `value=3` will not work. To get around this, I'd like to use the *x,y* solutions for to be the initial values for the next iteration. For example, for *a=1* the solution is `[10.999999998] [0.99999999999]` which I'd like to be the initial values for the next iteration at *a=2*:

```
x = m.Var(value=10.999999998,lb=0)
y = m.Var(value=0.99999999999,lb=0)
```

and so on until it gets to *a=10*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m.Param()` for `a` so that `a.value` can be adjusted with every loop. The `x.value` and `y.value` can also be adjusted to give an initial guess. Gekko automatically stores the prior solution as the new initial guess so it is not required to reinitialize `x` and `y`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

av = np.linspace(1,10,10)
xv = 3; yv = 3

a = m.Param()
b = m.Const(value=1)
x = m.Var(value=xv,lb=0)
y = m.Var(value=yv,lb=0)

m.Equation(10**-x + y == a)
m.Equation(x - 10**y == b)

for ai in av:
    a.value = ai
    x.value = xv
    y.value = yv

    m.solve(disp=False)

    # print solution
    xv = np.round(x.value[0],2)
    yv = np.round(y.value[0],2)
    print(f'a: {np.round(ai,2)} x: {xv} y: {yv}')
```

This gives solutions:

```
a: 1.0 x: 11.0 y: 1.0
a: 2.0 x: 101.0 y: 2.0
a: 3.0 x: 1001.0 y: 3.0
a: 4.0 x: 10001.0 y: 4.0
a: 5.0 x: 100001.0 y: 5.0
a: 6.0 x: 1000001.0 y: 6.0
a: 7.0 x: 10000001.0 y: 7.0
a: 8.0 x: 100000001.0 y: 8.0
a: 9.0 x: 1000000001.0 y: 9.0
a: 10.0 x: 10000000001.0 y: 10.0
```

Another way to solve this is with `IMODE=2` to solve all of the permutations in `a` at once. For this problem it takes an initialization with `IMODE=3`. This is potentially much faster so that one larger optimization problem is solved instead of a series of optimization problems.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

a = m.Param(value=1)
b = m.Const(value=1)
x = m.Var(value=3,lb=0)
y = m.Var(value=3,lb=0)

m.Equation(10**-x + y == a)
m.Equation(x - 10**y == b)

m.options.IMODE=3
m.solve(disp=False)

m.options.IMODE=2
a.value=np.linspace(1,10,10)
m.solve(disp=False)

for i,ai in enumerate(a.value):
    xv = np.round(x.value[i],2)
    yv = np.round(y.value[i],2)
    print(f'a: {np.round(ai,2)} x: {xv} y: {yv}')
```

The result is the same:

```
a: 1.0 x: 11.0 y: 1.0
a: 2.0 x: 101.0 y: 2.0
a: 3.0 x: 1001.0 y: 3.0
a: 4.0 x: 10001.0 y: 4.0
a: 5.0 x: 100001.0 y: 5.0
a: 6.0 x: 1000001.0 y: 6.0
a: 7.0 x: 10000001.0 y: 7.0
a: 8.0 x: 100000001.0 y: 8.0
a: 9.0 x: 1000000001.0 y: 9.0
a: 10.0 x: 10000000001.0 y: 10.0
```